# How to integrate "Length x Width x Height" dimensions searchable form with in WordPress WooCommerce?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

I'm working on adding a search form or filter to search all products in the shop based on specific box dimensions : length x width x height (ex: 4 x 4 x 2").

Here are 2 websites with examples of what I'm trying to replicate in WooCommerce - WordPress shop.
1. http://www.boxpartners.com/Shop/C5-LEN9to11.aspx
2. http://www.unitedcontainer.com/store (in sidebar)

I've tested many WooCommerce plugin and extensions for product filters and advanced search forms, but I can't get any of them to function exactly. I can populate a dropdown with a list of all dimensions, but I'd like the ability for the user to input the dimensions in 3 separate fields.